# How call method based on Json Object scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I Have two functions like below

```
def method1(ip:String,r:Double,op:String)={
val data = spark.read.option("header", true).csv(ip).toDF()
val r3= data.select("c", "S").dropDuplicates("C", "S").withColumn("R", lit(r))
r3.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(op)
}

def method2(ip:String,op:String)={
val data = spark.read.option("header", true).csv(ip).toDF()
val r3= data.select("c", "S").dropDuplicates("C", "StockCode")
r3.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(op)
}
```

I want to call this methods by based on Json object parameter .
for example if my input json is like below

```
{"name":"method1","ip":"Or.csv","r":1.0,"op":"oppath"}
```

It has to call `method1` and `"Or.csv",1.0,”oppath"` as parameters I.e. in json object name indicate method name, and reaming fields are parameters.

Please help me on this.

Comment: You'll need to parse the JSON and look for an `eval` alternative in Scala. You'll have to dynamically execute code which can get ugly sometimes. Narrow your use cases and use `match - case` or `if - else`

Answer (score 0):

First we need to read Json through spark into a dataframe.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("path to the json file")
```

which should be give you dataframe as

```
scala> df.show()
+------+-------+------+---+
|    ip|   name|    op|  r|
+------+-------+------+---+
|Or.csv|method1|oppath|1.0|
+------+-------+------+---+
```

Next

```
   scala> def method1(ip:String,r:Double,op:String)={
         | val data = spark.read.option("header", true).csv(ip).toDF()
         | val r3= data.select("c", "S").dropDuplicates("C", "S").withColumn("R", lit(r))
         | r3.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(op)
         | }

method1: (ip: String, r: Double, op: String)Unit
```

next

```
   scala> def method2(ip:String,op:String)={
         | val data = spark.read.option("header", true).csv(ip).toDF()
         | val r3= data.select("c", "S").dropDuplicates("C", "StockCode")
         | r3.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(op)
         | }

method2: (ip: String, op: String)Unit
```

next

```
scala>df.withColumn("methodCalling",when($"name" === "method1",method1(df.first().getString(1),df.first().getDouble(2),df.first().getString(3))).otherwise(when($"name" === "method2", method2(df.first().getString(1),df.first().getString(2)))))
```

it will call method1  or method2 based on Json Object.